# NX React App with Typescript - Code Splitting not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, code-splitting, nxjs

My react app inside NX workspace monorepo having code splitting unable and following are version details

`"@nx/react": "17.1.3", "@nx/web": "17.1.3", "@nx/webpack": "17.1.3", "@nx/workspace": "17.1.3",   "typescript": "5.3.2", "react-router": "^6.20.1",`

After enabling code splitting at app level inside routes.tsx, All the components are loaded inside src_bootstrap.tsx file ignoring code splitting,

Already tried with `module: esnext` configuration inside the tsconfig.json file but no luck, any suggestions will be helpful.